# Putting quotation marks inside a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, file

```
def add_div(filename, caption):

    test = str(filename)
    return ('<div><img src=' + test + '><br><p>' + caption + '</p></div>')


def add_body(image_dict, s, order = None):
    '''(dict of {str:list of str}, str, list) -> str

    If the third parameter is passed, then the filenames
    included in the body should only be those in the list and should be added
    in the same order as they are listed in the list. '''
    new = ''
    s = '<html><head></head>'

    while order is None:
       for (key, value) in image_dict.items():
           new  += add_div(str(key), str(value[2]))
       return (s + '<body><div id="slideshow">'  + new + '</body>'+ '</html>')
```

The output of add_body function is:
    [image]

how do I get quotation marks around the word images/skater.jpg ?

this is what the file looks like 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have two separate options:

1) Use double quotes

```
print("Hey that's pretty cool!")
```

2) Escape the single quotation mark

```
print('Hey that\'s pretty cool!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the quotation marks in the string that you are concatenating like this :

```
def add_div(filename, caption):

    test = str(filename)
    return ('<div><img src="' + test + '"><br><p>' + caption + '</p></div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one type of `quotation` for the `string` definition and the other for the included `quotes`:

```
>>> "bob said: 'hello'"
"bob said: 'hello'"
>>> "I said 'yo bob, how u doing?' in reply"
"I said 'yo bob, how u doing?' in reply"
```

---

So to fix your problem, just change the `return` statement in the first `function` to:

```
return ('<div><img src="' + test + '><br><p>'" + caption + '</p></div>')
```

---

*Note that as a final thing, the parenthesis in the `return` statement aren't required as `return` is a not a `function` or `method`.*

Answer (score 0):

Good answers, but another method is to escape the single or double quotation mark with `\`

Example:

```
# this is the same as
# s = "'"
s = '\''
print(s)

#this is the same as
# s = '"'
s = "\""
print(s)
```